# Unity3D packet manager / dependency manager

Tags: unity-game-engine, dependencies, git-submodules, dependency-management

My team comes from app and websites development so we are used to writing reusable code, libraries etc. We usually put this stuff open source and we manage the dependencies with tools like npm, gradle, cocoapods etc.

Is there anything for Unity3D multiplatform (Mac OS & Windows)?

I saw only rudimental solutions in the web or based on nuget which is windows only.

Basically, I would like to have something like the asset store: importing versioned dependencies. These dependencies can be complete projects like the ones in the asset store. In my ideal solution, the dependencies are stored in git repositories on GitHub/Bitbucket/etc.

The only way I found by myself by now is using git submodules but they are not the best way to manage the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, the Unity Asset Store is the closest thing to a public package manager for Unity since it allows you to easily download and import asset packages into your project from the Download/Import view.

See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetStore.html

Another option, particularly useful for private assets that you don't want to publish to the store, is to build and maintain your own set of Asset Packages. Asset Packages allow you to encapsulate related assets in a single file for easy sharing and reuse. Asset packages also support versioning and incremental updates, similar to what you're looking for.

See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackages.html